# element.setAttribute vs element.style. performance

Tags: javascript

I have only one simple question.
Which is faster?

```
element.setAttribute('style','background-image:url("icons/'+imageName+'")');
```

Or

```
element.style.backgroundImage = 'url("icons/'+imageName+'")';
```

Comment: The second one will be _slightly_ faster as the browser won't need to parse the _flattened_ CSS properties from the `style=""` attribute - but in both cases it still needs to parse your `url()` property value and then load the image: and the _comparatively eons of time_ needed to load an image from the network (or even the browser's cache on your local disk) will completely wipe-out any difference in perf skipping the `style=""` attribute had.

Comment: @dandavis Standard element attributes are reflected to the DOM properties and vice versa, so both are set despite of what you set in the code.

Comment: @Teemu:  i know the mutations and all that fire regardless, but i was thinking .style was on the naughty list (https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a), but it's not. maybe it should be, certainly some of it's usages will cause reflow...

Comment: @dandavis Well, AFAIK reflow usually takes place when you're reading a value from the _mutated_ DOM, setting a property/attribute rarely causes reflow.

Comment: @dandavis that means setAttribute is faster and uses less resources?

Comment: @redevil [If there's a difference](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/), it's negligible, you should not worry about it.

Comment: I have one complex question: why do you think this matters?

Comment: @Kaiido Because i need to generate bunch of HTML elements (500 elements every 5 seconds) and append them to DOM with CSS background-image property

Comment: Performance always matters broooo oooo ooo oo o o

Comment: Then measure. But do it many times, on many devices and browsers. But I doubt you'll find any meaningful difference. The .style getter might introduce as much or more slowness than the attribute parsing. But then the real question: why are you using any of these two solutions? Why can't you use a CSS stylesheet?

Comment: @Kaiido Why can't you use a CSS stylesheet? Because images have different names